# Publishing two versions of the same application, optimized for different handsets, as an update

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, android-install-apk, android-version

I am in a situation where I have to publish two variants of the same application which are optimized for different devices (one for a specific HTC, other for all the other devices)
I want to be able to publish both the apps specifying which one is compatible with which device.

Is it something that I'll be controlling with the `Manifest` file?
If yes, then how!?

The typical scenario is, I have a separate version for `HTC Inspire 4G`, and another version for every other phone.
How do I upload these two to the market when:

- The app is supposed to be an upgrade
- The app is a fresh upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, each application on market must have unique package. So you are out of luck to upgrade single application to different ones depending on device.

I'd suggest that you make accommodations for `Inspire 4G` in your code. I suspect that differences are not that significant to warrant two applications.

Comment: Hmm.. I figured out how to find out names of the devices, so now I think I'll go for having the same application :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the only difference in the interphases?  You could probably combine the projects using alternate layouts.

If you absolutely MUST have two separate apps, I think you may have to copy the contents of your project over to a new file, since the android market won't allow you to publish multiple apps with the same package name (it will stop you from uploading any app witht the same namespace and ask you to upgrade the first app instead).

I think your only options are to somehow combine the code into one app that distinguishes between the devices internally somehow, or to create two completely seperate projects, and publish them under similar names.

Comment: The difference is not in the layouts, but in the way they handle database. HTC Inspire 4G just fails to copy the database from asset/raw folder to internal database folder. thus I had to devise a different way of handling it altogether